# Best way to solve a lot of queries stuck because of no index

Tags: postgresql, index

#### Environment

- PostgreSQL 9.4
- 16 GB RAM  8 Cores
- max_iops: 8000

#### What problem I encountered

Last night our production environment database encountered a large amount of traffic, whcih caused the cpu load to approach 100% and the number of active connections approached more than 600. Most of the connections are querying the same table, and stuck there.
Then I found this table has 800,000 rows and does not have any indexes.
[image]

#### What I have tried

I created a index on this table without concurrently. A few minutes later, there were no more stuck queries.

#### What I want

Although I have solved this problem, but I think this approach is risky! Because the database server is already busy, the ddl operations may be the last straw to kill the camel. Is there any  safer and more sufficient way to solve this problem?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name yep

Comment: Unrelated, but: are you aware that Postgres 9.4 is [no longer](https://www.postgresql.org/support/versioning/) supported or maintained?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Thanks for your reminding,  using postgresql 9.4 does bring a lot of trouble.

Answer (score 1):

> found this table has 800,000 rows and does not have any indexes

> Is there any safer and more sufficient way to solve this problem?

Only really re-emptive work:

- Proper design work up-front so there are no large tables with no indexes, or not common queries that are not well-supported by the existing indexes. This might be out of your hands if you don't work directly with the development team for the application, but as a DBA you could monitor your databases for potentially worrying structures (i.e. a table with no keys/indexes, regular slow running queries if you log those, ...). Recheck after application updates, in case a structure migration has failed silently and left indexes undefined that the developers have added.
- Load testing on the application to make sure no such issues are likely (you often can't rule them out entirely, but you can certainly minimise the risk). Again, this may be out of your hands.

> but I think this approach is risky

A long index build, especially if done as an offline operation so could hold up all other access to the table, could be problematic, but when this happens adding the index is the only solution. Perhaps go for an online index build if possible - that will take longer but won't completely block part of the application while it does the job.

Also, if you have a dev copy of the system, test the new indexing changes there before applying to production to avoid making a change that will take ages to apply and have little of the benefit you are needing.